# error="abi: improperly formatted output:

Tags: go-ethereum, abi, bytecode, binance-smart-chain, validators

I have modified the bsc genesis contract and added only more function:

```
function addValidator(address _consensusAddress) public {

currentValidatorSet.push(Validator({
    consensusAddress: _consensusAddress,
    feeAddress: address(0), // default to address(0) for uninitialized addresses
    BBCFeeAddress: address(0), // default to address(0) for uninitialized addresses
    votingPower: 0, // default to 0 for uninitialized voting power
    jailed: false, // default to false for uninitialized jail status
    incoming: 0 // default to 0 for uninitialized incoming
}));
}
```

It was compiled properly but constantly getting error: "abi improperly formatted"